# CORS, Client vs. Server & Rails API GET Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, curl, client

I've built a GET Rails API that checks for an access token and that the registered request.env["HTTP_X_REAL_IP"] matches the IP address that is registered within the admin panel of the app.

Example request:

https://staging.mysite.com/api/v1/products?access_token=7b9f3cddd3914a6f45fa692997fe6dc9

The API works great when I'm making requests from a server by curling the request or by making the request on hurl.it.

My question is: what happens if the API request comes from a client vs. a server? I have the rack-cors gem installed but I think that the API would register the user's computer IP vs. the server's IP. Any advice is appreciated.

FWIW: the expected users of the API will likely be using Rails.

As a bonus: if anyone has a recommendation of a service where I can test the API as a client, I would be thankful.

Comment: There is no difference between a client and a server as the origin of the request. The question is who is going to be responsible to set the header and how do you protect yourself from spoofing? Is your application going to be behind a load-balancer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP of the client can change frequently and will only show the IP of their ISP, so limiting an API that may get called from the browser by IP might not be a good idea. CORS is related to resources (javascript, fonts, etc.) loaded by the browser over different domains.

If you're referring to testing as in debugging, Chrome has an extension called [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) that you could use for REST API testing. If you're looking for a service that'll test for uptime, Pingdom might be of use?

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to make it clear that the API is to be consumed server side only. I will definitely try Postman. I've been impressed with Paw so far.